# Langrage Multipliers with two constraints (Efficient Calculation)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose I have to minimize $x^2 + 2y^2 +3z^2$ under $x+y+z = 1$ and $x+2y+3z = k$ where $k$ is a constant and I also require $x,y,z$ to be between $0$ and $1$.

I know the traditional way of Lagrange Multiplier Method but the k complicates the arithmetic, is there any tricks/immediate observations I could make to solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: solve for $y,z$ in terms of $x$, and plug them into the expression $x^2+2y^2+3z^2$ and use $1$st derivative test to settle the answer.

Comment: What do you mean solve for y and z in terms of x? Such as y = 1 -x - z and plug into x^2+2y^2+3z^2

Comment: As Jacob wrote, consider that $x$ is a constant. The two constraints make two linear equations in $y$ and $z$; solve them : so $y=f(x)$, $z=g(x)$. Now replace in the objective function which only depends on $x$. Otherwise Lagrange is simple.